# Cannot access empty property - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the current week with the following MSSQL query in Laravel 4:

```
DB::connection('db')->select("select DATEPART(week, '" . $today . "')");
```

However this returns

> Type: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
>   Message: Cannot access empty property
>   File: C:\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php

My guess is that it doesn`t work if there is no "from" statement, which is strange. Any suggestions on how can I workaround this will be appreciated.

Comment: DB::connection('db') is not set properly , check your driver

Comment: Nope. It works perfectly if i place any select with from statement. Apparently this is not supposed to work without it and google says nothing about this problem.